# Python: read variable number of columns of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, multiple-columns

By default, my python script will take data from stdin and write to stdout. However, if I specify certain command line options, then I can read from a file and or write to a file.

The script will only read two columns of numbers, which are separated by tabs and/or spaces. I need it such that it will read 2 or more columns of numbers (I have other scripts where I pipe the output of one of these to the input of another).

Here is what I have:

```
def main(argv):
  fin=sys.stdin
  fout=sys.stdout
  w=3
  plot=False
  graph=False
  ifile="stdin"
  ofile="stdout"
  filt="Median"
  ydata=False
  try:
      opts, args=getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:w:ps:qf:y",["ifile=","ofile="])
  except getopt.GetoptError:
    print sys.argv[0] + ' [-i <inputfile>] [-o <outputfile>] [-w <int>] [-p] [-s <imagefile>] [-q] [-f <int>] [-y]'
    sys,exit(1)
  for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt=='-h':
      print sys.argv[0] + ' [-i <inputfile>] [-o <outputfile>] [-w <int>] [-p] [-s <imagefile>] [-q] [-f <int>] [-y]n'
      print '   -w  filter window size (default=3)'
      print '   -p  display plot'
      print '   -s  save plot as imagefile (eps, jpeg, jpg, pdf, pgf, png, ps, raw, rgba, svg, svgz, tif, tiff)'
      print '   -i  if no inputfile is specified, read from STDIN'
      print '   -o  if no outputfile is specified, print to STDOUT'
      print '   -f  integer: 1=median (default), 2=moving average, 3=Wiener'
      print '   -q  quiet; suppress output'
      print '   -y  include y-data in output'
      sys.exit()
    elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
      ifile=arg
    elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
      ofile=arg
    elif opt in ("-q"):
      ofile="/dev/null"
    elif opt in ("-w"):
      w=int(arg)
    elif opt in ("-p"):
      plot=True
    elif opt in ("-f"):
      if int(arg)==2:
        filt="Moving Average"
      elif int(arg)==1:
        filt="Median"
      elif int(arg)==3:
        filt="Wiener"
    elif opt in ("-s"):
      graph=True
      imagefile=arg
    elif opt in ("-y"):
      ydata=True

  fin=open(ifile,'r')
  lines=fin.readlines()
  fin.close()

# Initialize two lists
  xl = []
  y1l = []

  for line in lines:
      p = line.split()
      xl.append(float(p[0]))
      y1l.append(float(p[1]))

# Convert the lists to arrays
  x = np.array(xl)
  y1 = np.array(y1l)

  if filt=="Median":
    yf=median(y1,width=w)
  elif filt=="Moving Average":
    yf=movingaverage(y1,w)
  elif filt=="Wiener":
    yf=wiener(y1,mysize=w)

  fout=open(ofile,'w')
  if ydata:
    outdata=np.array([x,y1,yf])
    fmt=['%4.1f','%13.5e','%13.5e']
  else:
    outdata=np.array([x,yf])
    fmt=['%4.1f','%13.5e']
  outdata=outdata.T
  np.savetxt(fout, outdata, fmt)
  fout.close()
```

The first column will be stored in a list called xl and then converted to an array called x.

The second column will be stored in a list called y1l and then converted to an array called y1.

The third column, if there is one, will be stored in a list called y2l and then converted to an array called y2.

And so on.

And the number of columns should be stored in a variable.

Or, perhaps, maybe it would be better to store all the input data into a multidimensional list and then array? I actually don't even need the lists; they are only used in intermediate steps to get the data into arrays. If it is possible to skip storing the data in lists, and directly into arrays, then that would be better.

Comment: Please include `import` lines and defined methods such as *movingaverage*, *median*, *weiner* for reproducibility. And how should variable columns after two be calculated? Medians/moving avgs/weiners of entire array? Is first column, *xl* an indicator field?

Comment: The functions are irrelevant; they don't have anything to do with the questions I asked.  You can make something up:

    def median(x,w):
       return x

   def movingaverage(x,w):
      return x

   def wiener(x,w):
      return x

The imports are:

    import sys, getopt
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to load the text file directly with all columns avoiding the `for` loop with nested list. Then, if needed use [`numpy.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) to run functions across columns.

```
mat = np.loadtxt(ifile, delimiter="\t")

if filt=="Median":
    output_mat = np.apply_along_axis(median, 0, w)

elif filt=="Moving Average":
    output_mat = np.apply_along_axis(movingaverage, 0, w)

elif filt=="Wiener":
    output_mat = np.apply_along_axis(weiner, 0, w)

np.savetxt(ofile, output_mat, delimiter='\t')
```

Comment: So far so go.  Suppose I want to plot the data...

inline `import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if="2col.dat"

dat=np.loadtxt(if1)

plt.plot(dat[:,0],dat[:,1])
plt.show()`

This is fine if I know there are two columns. But what if there are more columns, and I don't know how many?

Suppose I want the first column to be the 'x' axis, and the rest to be 'y1', 'y2', ..., 'yn', and 'n' is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up that works.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# set the default input to STDIN
infile=sys.stdin

# load the data from input
data=np.loadtxt(infile)
rows=len(data)
cols=len(data[0])

# find the minimum and maximum x-values
xmin=min(data[:,0])
xmax=max(data[:,0])

# create the plot
fig=plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(16,9)
fig.set_dpi(120)
plt.plot(data[:,0],data[:,1:])
plt.ylim(ymin=1e-6)
plt.xlim(xmin,xmax)
plt.grid(which='major',linestyle='-',linewidth='0.3')
plt.xlabel('energy (eV/u)')
plt.ylabel(r'cross section (10$^{-16}$ cm$^{2}$)')
plt.xscale('log',basex=10)
plt.yscale('log',basey=10)
plt.show()
```